# Meaning of "to undertake the siege of someone's virtue" in "He wished now that he had never undertaken the siege of Miss Wilkinson's virtue" (Maugham)

Tags: sentence-meaning, literature

> Of course it was much easier for Frenchmen to do these things; the
>   language was such an aid; Philip could never help feeling that to say
>   passionate things in English sounded a little absurd. **He wished now
>   that he had never undertaken the siege of Miss Wilkinson's virtue**; the
>   first fortnight had been so jolly, and now he was wretched; but he was
>   determined not to give in, he would never respect himself again if he
>   did, and he made up his mind irrevocably that the next night he would
>   kiss her without fail.
>
> *Of Human Bondage  by W. Somerset Maugham*

Can you paraphrase **the bold** sentence for me?

Comment: At least *a guess* to show an own attempt, please?

Comment: Seriously I don't get it except that he regrets whatever he had done with Miss Wilkinson.

Comment: He wanted to have **[an affair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affair)** with Miss Wilkinson. According to the societal customs of that age, a virtuous woman should have rebuffed a man's initial attemps at establishing physical intimacy. He undertook the siege of this "virtue" by expressing his affection to Miss Wilkinson through the meager means provided by the English language (that is, meager compared to those afforded by French).

Comment: @CopperKettle  Thank you. I've got it. I misunderstood the meaning of 'to undertake the siege of something' in the first place. Why don't you write an answer for this question so that I can wrap up this question with a bow?

Comment: Okay, I've posted my comment as an answer! (0: "Of Human Bondage" is a nice book with a good ending. I also like The Painted Veil and The Moon and Sixpence.

Comment: It is a metaphor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He wanted to have an affair with Miss Wilkinson. According to the societal customs of that age, a virtuous woman should have rebuffed a man's initial attemps at establishing physical intimacy. He undertook the siege of this "virtue" by expressing his affection to Miss Wilkinson through the meager means provided by the English language (that is, meager compared with those afforded by French).

Comment: *compared to* sounded fine ;)

Comment: @User1 - thanks! I suddenly recalled reading on "to vs with". I'm also unsure about "undertook **the** siege" vs. "undertook **a** siege". (0: